# ¿Cómo poner valor a un input que se encuentra dentro de un form ? con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Quiero saber como imprimir un valor en un `input` que se encuentra en un `Form` dentro de un `Modal` con `jQuery`, si pongo el `input` fuera del `Form` lo imprime normalmente pero cuando coloco el `input` dentro del `Form` no lo hace.

Esta es la función que uso para traer el valor que quiero imprimir(funciona correctamente)

```js
 // ABRIR EL MODAL
   $('#btnAddClase').click(function(){
      ultimocontador();
      $('#modalclase').modal('show');
      $('#modalclase').find('.modal-title').text('Nueva Clase');
    });
 
 // FUNCION CONTADOR
 function ultimocontador() {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '<?php echo base_url() ?   >mantenimiento/logistica/clase/ultimocontador',
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
      var  html = "";
      var i ;
      var con = 0 ; 
       var suma = 0;
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      con = data[i].contador;
      suma = parseInt(con)+ 1;
       html += suma;
      }
$("#contador1").val(html);   // <-  QUIERO IMPRIMIR   LA VARIABLE HTML EN EL INPUT DENTRO DEL FORM
} ,
    error: function(){
     swal({
    title: "Error!",
    text: "Ocurrio un error!",
    icon: "error",
    button: "Aceptar",
    });
    }
});
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BOTON PARA ABRIR EL MODAL -->
 <div class="box-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success "          id="btnAddClase">
      Crear Nuevo
    </button>
  </div>

<!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalclase" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><b></b></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="" method="POST" id="form_clase">
          <input type="hidden" name="txtIdClase" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contador1" name="contador" required="true"> <!--AQUI QUIERO IMPRIMIRLO-->
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Contador<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Digitar Nueva Clase <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nClase" name="nClase" required="true">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnsaveClase" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? por favor.

Comment: Intenta cambiar: $("#contador1").val(html); por $("#contador1").val("probando"); Si al abrirse tu modal tiene el valor que le pusistes es que tienes que ejecutar el código de abrir tu modal dentro del success del ajax

Comment: No igual no me muestra  nada

Comment: pon un console.log("probando"); donde tenias el código anterior y revisa la consola a ver que te muestra

Comment: Si en consola si me muestra el valor que quiero pero  ala hora de imprimirlo no deja

Comment: Por cierto cuando usaba un div en vez de un input si lo imprimia pero eso no me servia ya que ese valor lo quiero para enviarlo method get a un controlador e insertarlo a la base de datos

Comment: intenta llamar a la funcion despues de abrir el modal

Comment: Estoy haciendo eso despues del  $('#btnAddClase').click(function()

Comment: llama la funcion ultimocontador() despues de abrir el modal $('#modalclase').modal('show');

Comment: no se puede reproducir tu error con el código que mostraste, será algo difícil poder ayudarte

Comment: Disculpen me olvide responder , ya solucione el problema Gracias alanfcm  no me percate que  reseteaba el modal y despues de llamar a la funcion

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos mi error fue abrir el modal despues de llamar la funcion

```js
  // ERROR 
  
 $('#btnAddClase').click(function(){
      ultimocontador();  <-- LLAMA A LA FUNCION
      $('#modalclase').modal('show');  <-- SE ABRE EL MODAL
      $('#modalclase').find('.modal-title').text('Nueva Clase');
    });
```

La forma de hacerlo era primero  abrir el modal y despues llamar a la funcion

```js
 $('#btnAddClase').click(function(){
      $('#modalclase').modal('show');  <-- SE ABRE EL MODAL
      ultimocontador();  <-- LLAMA A LA FUNCION
      $('#modalclase').find('.modal-title').text('Nueva Clase');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar dando un valor a tu variable  **html**, pues inicialmente no trae datos, para cuando la mandes a llamar te muestres el valor asignado. Ej:

```
var  html = "nuevo valor";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form_clase").find("#contador1").val(variable);
```

Ya revisaste que si de verdad te regresa información tu variable?